# Java: Closing Streams: Streams non-NULL even after close()

Tags: java

In my finally clause I clean up any streams, e.g.,

```
            finally // Clean up 
            {
                if (os != null) {
                    try {
                        os.close();
                    }
                    catch (IOException ioe) {
                        logger.warn("Failed to close outputStream", ioe);
                    }
                }
                if (is != null) {
                    try {
                        is.close();
                    }
                    catch (IOException ioe) {
                        logger.warn("Failed to close inputStream", ioe);
                    }
                }
```

But I see that the Streams remain non-NULL even after closing. So is it wrong to check for NULL? Or do I not see the result of `close` ?

Comment: Are you using Java 7? if so, look at try-with-resources, then you don't even have to worry about closing the streams as it will be handled for you (as long as they implement autoclosable, which most things like BufferedInputStream do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stream "object" is a reference to a instance of a stream. Whether the stream is open or not is part of its state. The close function is a function that runs in the objects state and thus will not affect references to it.

The reference will stay non-NULL until you set it null, but the stream's state is closed meaning that you cant use it anymore.

Comment: Is there a way to check if it's closed? And should that be used as the criterion?

Comment: @geneb. According to these posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655901/how-to-check-whether-an-outputstream-is-closed and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981196/how-to-know-if-a-bufferedreader-stream-is-closed you will not be able to see... But the close function will never throw an exception.  You could say: "os=null; is=null" after the closing to make the references null. But if the function finishes after the closing it is not needed. Your code is good as it is ;)